# Правила Google Play

Tags: google-play

Доброго времени суток. Чтобы уменьшить размер игры (.apk) планирую добавить в игру функцию загрузки больших изображений с облачного хранилища. Кто хорошо знаком с правилами Google Play или осуществлял подобное, не буду ли я нарушать правила Google Play? Надо ли дополнительно уведомлять пользователя, что загрузка будет производиться из интернета?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не нужно об этом уведомлять, если загружаемые изображения не будут нарушать другие правила (вроде порнографии и т.д.). В противном случае приложение будет заблокировано.